# Why do floats not respect their parent height in some instances and do in others?

Tags: html, css

This is a "why" question rather than a "how to" question.  
I'm learning floats right now and one issue I keep encountering is that setting the float height as a % value will not be respected if the float is contained with clearfix. If the parent element is taken out of normal flow with display:table or position:absolute or whatever, then the float height % will be respected. 
Why do float height % values not work with clearfix on the parent? Why does this issue not affect width % values? Why do display: table and position: absolute work while clearfix doesn't?

I've searched stackoverflow and all of the answers discuss "how to" rather than the "why".

Comment: share a code that demonstrate what you are saying. It make things easier to understand

Comment: Just tested it out again and it seems like it may have to do with the parent container using % and the floating children using % as well. When I set the parent to vw/vh, the float fills up the height appropriately. So it's likely an issue with having %s for nested elements. 
I've used % for both parent & child before on non-floats and it's worked, but from my googling it seems to be best practice to not have % for both. 
I'll delete this question tomorrow since my question is based on some incorrect assumptions.

Comment: It's really very difficult to help without having an example. For instance, we don't know when you are setting the parent to % dimensions what those are %s of as we have not seen your HTML structure or the relevant CSS being applied. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.